# Remove Scientific notation from csv output

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .json file which I am reading to pandas.
Then I am exporting the dataframe to .csv. However, the input '40007207255820210316' from the .json is being written as '40007207255820200000' in the csv as it is getting converted to a scientific notation.
How can I get the exact value written to the csv as from the original .json.

```
data=pd.read_json("file.json")
data.rename(columns = {'Key_number':'Key'}, inplace = True)
data.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

No other manipulations are taking place on this column.

Comment: Hi. Can you please the output of `np.iinfo(np.int64)` and `np.finfo(np.float64).max`?

Comment: iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)

1.7976931348623157e+308

Answer (score 2):

If you check [numpy Data Types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) you'll find that maximum `int64` allowed is

```
np.iinfo(np.int64).max
9223372036854775807
```

and maximum `float64` is

```
np.finfo(np.float64).max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

your number `40007207255820210316` is greater than maximum `int64`

```
40007207255820210316 > np.iinfo(np.int64).max
True
```

but less than maximum `float64`

```
40007207255820210316 > np.finfo(np.float64).max
False
```

so when you load the json, numbers will be loaded as dtype `float64`

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json')
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   value   2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 144.0 bytes
```

and if you try to load with dtype `int64` you'd get an error

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json', dtype=np.int64)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Thus, if you only need to load json and then write the DataFrame as csv you can do

```
df = pd.read_json('file_scientific.json', dtype=str)
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   value   2 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

in this way, it's not read as number but as string, and it'll be written as you want in the csv

```
df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly don't need to do any manipulation, you can read everything in as strings with:

```
data = pd.read_json("file.json", dtype=str)
```

This will avoid any loss of precision you are getting in numeric values where pandas is trying to automatically infer dtypes.

Technically, `dtype=False` is the correct way to do this [according to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html), but the intention of `dtype=str` (or equivalently, `dtype=object`) is clearer and works as well.